# is this sentence grammatically correct? emphasizing the word memorizing

Tags: grammaticality

"Wrapping memo notes at your wrist makes you memorizing easily", i feel not confident wether it's grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be better:

"Wrapping memo notes **around** your wrist makes you **memorize it** easily".

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with "Wrapping memo notes *on* your wrist makes *memorizing it easier*".